# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'script' was never awaited content = str(content) if content is not None else None

Tags: python, async-await, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a discord bot in python3.8 along with discord.py, its purpose is to read a text file and then output each word as individual messages in a server.
Currently, this is the function I'm using to try and output the script as each individual message:

```
async def script():
    with open("test.py", 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            print('\n'.join(line.split()))
```

This function is then applied to the following:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('r!help'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Help')
    elif message.content.startswith('r!start'):
        channel = message.channel
        await script()
        await channel.send(script())
```

However, I end up with an error stating

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'script' was never awaited
  content = str(content) if content is not None else None
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I assume this is because my coroutine script isn't being awaited, but I am awaiting it as `await script()` but of course, that doesn't seem to work. Instead the script is being printed onto my terminal in the pycharm IDE, so not only is the coroutine not being awaited its not being sent to the appropriate channel in the server (which is probably because its not awaited). I would greatly appreciate it if someone could explain to me why the coroutine isn't being awaited and point me in the right direction on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You are awaiting **`script`** before but in **`await channel.send(script())`** you are not awaiting nonetheless this will give an error as **`script`** return None

Here is the revised code

**`script` function**:

```
async def script(channel):
    with open("test.py", 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            await channel.send('\n'.join(line.split()))
```

**`on_message` event**:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('r!help'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Help')
    elif message.content.startswith('r!start'):
        channel = message.channel
        await script(channel)
```